# Devexpress MVC Custom Data Binding using DataTable

Tags: gridview, ado.net, devexpress-mvc

I am trying to implement the Large Database Custom Binding for a Devexpress MVC Gridview ([Custom Binding Demo](https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxGridViewDemos/DataBinding/AdvancedCustomBinding)) but the project doesn't use Entity Framework's DataContext but a DataTable as the datasource.

The Datatable converted to IQueryable does not render values in the grid as the grid expects POCO's when using .BindToCustomData().

Wrapping the DataTable's rows in a List bind the values but fails when grouping or sorting.

The Expando Object approach gets quite far, but when hitting the DevExpress.Data.Linq.CriteriaToExpressionConverter for sorting/grouping etc. it fails as CriteriaToExpressionConverter  seems to be trying to read properties using reflection causing an Argument exception as the dynamic properties of the ExpandoObject can't be read.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried reaching out to DevExpress support?

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not do DevExpress MVC Custom Data Binding using a DataTable.

I did reach out to DevExpress (excellent service) on this and after multiple discussions its clear that its just something to be avoided. Its not how the control was designed and forcing it is a waste of time. Use an ORM and let their control do the heavy lifting.

Following is my experience for anyone as insane as myself with this task and as evidence as to why this won't work.

1) You have to overwrite a large amount of boilerplate (thankfully they provide the bulk of it, but I still had to make a lot of modifications) which is then entirely your own to maintain and test.

2) Even then, you cannot bind a DataTable directly it has to be of type Queryable. But DataTable.AsQuerable() returns IQueryable which does not bind correct as a DataRow is essentially a Dictionary and its columns are not strong-typed, so it doesn't render any value in the grid. (I did not test with a strongly-typed datatable, see point 4)

3)While making it an ExpandoObject (dynamic) object will get it binding, but then you will also need to overwrite their ICriteriaToExpressionConverter to handle the System.Linq.Expressions.Expression that is built up when grouping, sorting, summarizing.

4)You would need a strongly typed object to get rid of points 2 and 3 but then you would also solve point 1.

Bottom line: Don't use DataTable with DevExpress Custom Data Binding;